# Cannot pass data between app delegate and storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to set one variable to NO when I receive local notification. In App Delegate I run:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
if ([[notification alertBody] isEqualToString:@"Time To Wake Up"]) {
    NLAlarmViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AlarmVC"];
    [vc setStarted:NO];
    }
}
```

In view controller class:

```
- (IBAction)twoTapsDetected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Two taps detected");
    if (started != YES ) {
        NSLog(@"Not Started");
    }
    else if (started != NO) {
        NSLog(@"Started");
    }
}
```

In log I have Started. But in App Delegate I set it to NO. When I make a breakpoint in Xcode started = YES, but should be NO. Maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: There might be two different instance of NLAlarmViewController. [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName....] create a new instance of NLAlarmViewController.

Comment: Could you please also post started property of NLAlarmViewController? Thanks.

Comment: Is started declared in your header file?

Comment: Yes it is declared in .h file

Comment: Please provide your code of pushing VC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform segue with identifier in the appdelegate on notification appears.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
if ([[notification alertBody] isEqualToString:@"Time To Wake Up"]) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueIdentifier" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Then use the story board delegate methods

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    //    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YourSegueIdentifier"]) {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
    NLAlarmViewController *vc = (NLAlarmViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
     [vc setStarted:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: App Delegate is not in the storyboard

Comment: NLAlarmViewController is in storyboard. Then you can use this code.